# Sparse Matrix Reordering

Tags: matrix, sparse-matrix, graph-theory

Matrix reorderings are important for many direct solvers. Sometimes the objective is to reduce the bandwith or the generated fill in by LU Decomposition. I am interested in a reordering which reduces the fill in of $A + A^{−1}$. Is there some work, or is it hopeless?

Comment: $A^{-1}$ is often dense even when $A$ is sparse (e.g., tridiagonal matrices have dense inverses, and any general matrix whose graph is strongly connected), in which case there is nothing to reorder in $A+A^{-1}$, it's dense. Can you give more context to make this question more clear/relevant to other people? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: There is an iterative newton scheme to compute the $sign$ of a matrix $A$, where $A$ has no eigenvalues on the imaginary axis. 
The iteration is as follows:
$A_{k+1}=A_{k}+A_{k}^{-1}$.
Yes it is true that you take the inverse of $A$ explicitly.

Comment: With that iteration, $A_k$ (in general) becomes dense after one iteration, and the questions of fill-in and reordering become irrelevant.

Comment: ok this means it is hopeless and we can close

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the explicit computation of $A^{-1}$ in the Newton iteration for the sign of $A$.

Refer to chapter 5 from this [book](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~higham/fm/OT104HighamChapter5.pdf) by Higham, more specifically equation 5.22.

Comment: yes but then your domain of convergence is smaller